# C# send custom socket string

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public static List<Socket> samp = new List<Socket>();

IPHostEntry host = null;
Socket sock;
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(sending ip..);

foreach (IPAddress address in host.AddressList)
{
    IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, 7777);
    sock = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sock.Connect(ipe);
    if (sock.Connected)
    {
        samp.Add(sock);
    }
}
```

This code work's **okay**. It send's my ip. How it looks in console:
[image]

**How can I send custom string**? For example i'm tried this code:

```
if (sock.Connected)
{
    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a test");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
    int i = sock.Send(msg);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sent {0} bytes.", i));
    samp.Add(sock);
}
```

It shows message: *Sent 14 bytes*. But in the console nothing prints.. How can I send this text to console? I'm also tried this:

```
sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a test"));
```

And this not prints :( 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string);`

Comment: Are you kidding? I'm creating it in winform, and send socket to console, console must print it...

Comment: Define your `console`

Comment: http://files.sa-mp.com/samp037_svr_R1_win32.zip ... I don't have source, or something like that. It's server file for game..